Ubuntu 24.04 Headless Remote Login?
Is it possible to use the Gnome Remote Login feature on Ubuntu 24.04 to have a session that is not displayed on physical monitor attached to the computer?

Does this answer your question? Ubuntu 22.04 remote desktop headless?

No, because Gnome 46 has new feature called Remote Login, provided by gnome-remote-desktop package. But i dont know how to use it. Can not find a documentation for that. I have a plain Ubuntu 24.04, which has Gnome Desktop(Xorg) and it is looks like conflicting with Remote Login feature. So i decided to ask it someone had success with that and how it could be used

Can you edit your question above and add exactly what you have tried and a screenshot of the Remote Login settings page? Also add if you are trying to remote login from another Ubuntu (or some other distro of Linux) or Windows and which RDP client app you are using in that computer.

I am using Wayland (the default on my VM) and I didn't have any problem using the new remote login feature.
